# alternative for provide in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I had used `provide` from @angular/core.

for eg.

```
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {ToastOptions} from "ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr";
let options = {
  positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
};

//then used inside providers array as :
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders,
    ConfigService,    
    ToastsManager,
    provide(ToastOptions, { useValue: new ToastOptions(options)})    
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but I cant find how to do this in angular 2 final?

any inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax has changed a bit since RC6, this is how it should be now:

```
{ provide: ToastOptions, useValue: new ToastOptions(options) }
```

You can also delete `import {provide} from '@angular/core';`, you don't need it anymore.